# Не вызывается метод внутри экземпляра класса в Python 3.7

Tags: python

Не удается получить доступ к методу read_file() внутри экземпляра
класса в Python 3.7. Требуется напечатать список `list_values_end` при помощи
функции `print_file()`. При вызове функции `print_file()` терминал
выдает `<__main__.ReadFile object at 0x0082EA70>` вместо ожидаемого списка.
Поясните, пожалуйста, что сделано не так? Код прилагается.

```
class ReadFile():
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.file_r = 'val_kWt.txt'
        self.read_file(self.file_r)
                
        self.print_file(self)
        
    def read_file(self, file_r):
        list_values_end = []
        vk = open(file_r, 'r')
        list_values = vk.readlines()
 
        for list_value in list_values:
            list_values_end.append(list_value.rstrip())
        
        vk.close()
        print(list_values_end)
         
        return list_values_end
        
    def print_file(self, list_values_end):
        print(list_values_end)

examp = ReadFile()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё вызывается. Нужно просто понимать, что `return` не только возвращает значение, но и завершает выполнение метода.

Поэтому когда вы пишите

```
return list_values_end
print(list_values_end)
```

то до `print` исполнение кода просто не дойдёт.

UPD: Ответ на исправленный вопрос:

Вы же в функцию вывода передаёте сам экземпляр класса. А надо передавать тот список, который хотите напечатать.

Вместо

```
self.read_file(self.file_r)            
self.print_file(self)
```

Сделайте

```
result = self.read_file(self.file_r)            
self.print_file(result)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но, наверное, я не точно сформулировал вопрос. Хотелось короче, но не получилось. Мне не удается получить доступ к списку `list_values_end` внутри класса. Например, если добавить функцию для чтения этого списка, то при вызове функции терминал выдает `<__main__.ReadFile object at 0x0082EA70>` вместо ожидаемого списка.

Comment: @ErshovYuri, я дополнил мой ответ

Comment: Большое Вам человеческое спасибо, Xander. Все работает. Несколько дней "бился", а оказалось так просто. Еще раз благодарю.